# Spring reload application context under demand

Tags: java, spring

I have a class that extends PropertyPlacerHolderConfig where once I startup the application is loaded with all the properties from database. Then the rest of Spring definition configuration use those properties, like scheduler time of my Quartz task for instance

But what I´m doing now is a management section of my application where a client can modify those properties in database. But so far the only way to make the application use those new values is restarting the service manually, and that´s what I want to avoid.

Regards.

Comment: Properties as in values from a `.properties` file? You can use a `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, but any property that was resolved will remain that way. Only new values that need to be resolved will have the updates.

Comment: I don't understand from the question why do you want to reload app context. If your application is working this means that it was built in war(I suppose you have web project if not specify it please) and deployed. After that you can't modify war and hence can't modify any property file.

Comment: You can force property reloading as the other comment states. But compile time set properties like that are typically best treated as constants (which is why there isn't a whole lot of support for dynamically modifying them - you have to do a bit of work to react to the events generated by changes). If you want to have user-configurable properties, you should implement and persist them somehow that won't be blown away by a redeployment (database, dao backed by config file on disk that's separate from the app context, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me explain you how it´s works. I have a class that extends PropertyPlacerHolderConfig where once I startup the application is loaded with all the properties from database. Then the rest of Spring definition configuration use those properties, like scheduler time of my Quartz task for instance.

Comment: But what I´m doing now is a management section of my application where a client can modify those properties in database. But so far the only way to make the application use those new values is restarting the service manually, and that´s what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload only those beans which needs updated configuration. Why whole application context every time ?
if Email configuration is updated, only email service needs that.

Simple code snippet will look something like this:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void onEmailConfChange()
{
Properties properties = dao.getEmailConf();
EmailService emailService = (EmailService) applicationContext
            .getBean("emailService");
emailService.setConfiguration(properties);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to provide a generic answer.
First of all you have to understand how exactly your application is supposed to react on these changes?

Example, lets say you manage the properties that denotes connection to the database.

Let's say these are stored in a database and get read by spring during the startup. The chances are that these properties are actually used by the data source bean.
Now what happens when you change, say, the host property of the database (migration to another server whatsoever)

Now the question is not how does spring reacts on this change, but how does the driver reacts on the change. In fact it should invalidate all the opened connections, close the connection pool, possibly clean up some application stuff (caches, monitoring and so forth), connect to another database.

This is not something that spring can do for you, in fact, the driver should be **able to deal with such an update**

Now two questions arise:
1. Whether all the application context should be updated upon this change?
2. How to identify and react to such a change?

As for the first question, the answer really depends on the properties you manage and what should the components really do upon the change.
But as a rule of thumb, don't reload the whole application context if you can, because its just too slow, in fact it doesn't differ much from rerunning the whole service.

As for the second question, you can use some messaging system to notify component(s) about the change. Then implement the listener that will manage the component upon the change.
Another variation is using an already existing tool [Zoo Keeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) It can manage the configuration, provides Out Of the Box support for asynchronous changes and so on.

Hope this helps